# WP get_post_thumbnail with Backstretch JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-backstretch

I am using a javascript that's called '[Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)' to display an image on the back of my website that resizes when the viewport is getting bigger or smaller. Now I would like to combine it with the [get_post_thumbnail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) function from WordPress so I can set a background image as featured image.

I tried the standard WP function but that doesn't work because it adds  tags:

```
 $.backstretch("<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>");
```

So I need to strip off those  tags.. I'm getting close because i'm now getting an url (and image) but it's always the same one even though I set a different featured image on every page

```
 <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id, $size, $attr ) ); ?>

 <script>$.backstretch("<?php echo $url; ?>");</script>
```

Comment: When inside loop use the_ID() instead $post_id

Comment: @MichalS sorry I don't know what you are trying to say...

Comment: When inside https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop (see samples there) use wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(the_ID(), $size, $attr ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the answer to your question in this tutorial: http://sridharkatakam.com/set-featured-image-full-sized-background-posts-pages-wordpress/

Create a backstretch-set.js-file and include
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("body").backstretch([BackStretchImg.src],{duration:3000,fade:750});
});`

and then enqueue both js-files (backstretch.js and your backstretch-set.js) in your functions.php

```
//* Enqueue Backstretch script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_backstretch' );
function enqueue_backstretch() {

//* Load scripts only on single Posts, static Pages and other single pages and only if featured image is present
if ( is_singular() && has_post_thumbnail() )

    wp_enqueue_script( 'backstretch', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'backstretch-set', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/backstretch-set.js' , array( 'jquery', 'backstretch' ), '1.0.0' );

    wp_localize_script( 'backstretch-set', 'BackStretchImg', array( 'src' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ) );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: OK, I included the necessary code from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the global $post object like so:

```
<?php global $post; $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'full' ) ); ?>

 <script>$.backstretch("<?php echo $url; ?>");</script>
```

Comment: In which file are you attempting this ? Are the backbone and jquery file loaded at the time you write this code ?

Comment: It's in my footer.php, the rest of the javascript code is in the header.php

Comment: In this case I must presume that something is changing your main query and thus you are not getting the correct post id in the footer of your page.

Comment: When i'm using the standard function: <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?> for example in a div then it gets the right image but I can't add that to the $.backstretch because it adds <img> ect.